# how to total up my array to make it one value and still remain in an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, count, eloquent

my function that i did to get the value based on user selected days is like :

```html
public function graphheheByDate(Request $request, $companyID)
{
$companyID = $this->decode($companyID);

$match = DiraChatLog::where('status','=','Match')->where('date_access', '>=', $request->from)->where('date_access', '<=', $request->to)
->selectRaw('DATE(date_access) as date, COUNT(1) as cnt') // created_at here is datetime format, only need the date portion using `DATE` function
->orderBy("date")
->groupBy("date")
->get() // return result set (collection) from query builder
->pluck('cnt') // only need the cnt column
->values() // array_values
->all(); // convert collection to array

$missing = DiraChatLog::where('status','=','Missing')->where('date_access', '>=', $request->from)->where('date_access', '<=', $request->to)
->selectRaw('DATE(date_access) as date, COUNT(1) as cnt') // created_at here is datetime format, only need the date portion using `DATE` function
->orderBy("date")
->groupBy("date")
->get() // return result set (collection) from query builder
->pluck('cnt') // only need the cnt column
->values() // array_values
->all(); // convert collection to array

$noAnswer = DiraChatLog::where('status','=','No Answer')->where('date_access', '>=', $request->from)->where('date_access', '<=', $request->to)
->selectRaw('DATE(date_access) as date, COUNT(1) as cnt') // created_at here is datetime format, only need the date portion using `DATE` function
->orderBy("date")
->groupBy("date")
->get() // return result set (collection) from query builder
->pluck('cnt') // only need the cnt column
->values() // array_values
->all(); // convert collection to array

// dd($match,$missing,$noAnswer);
$companyID = $this->encodeID($companyID);

return view('AltHr.Chatbot.graphhehe', compact('companyID'))->with('match',json_encode($match,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK))->with('missing',json_encode($missing,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK))->with('noAnswer',json_encode($noAnswer,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));     
}
```

so when i try and dd(); to show what values is showing i get this
[image]

so the values are correct based on the each date.
now i want to total up each array values for example in the first array i want it to 1 + 17 + 1 = 19

i want it to return 19. How can i do that? But i must return this in array format like the picture so in 3 arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest casting them to [Laravel collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collection) (or sum before casting to array) so you can just use the [`sum`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sum) method like this:

```
$matchSum = collect($match)->sum();
$missingSum = collect($missing)->sum();
$noAnswerSum = collect($noAnswer)->sum();
```

Or really, you should sum before casting to array:

```
$match = DiraChatLog::where('status','=','Match')
    ->where('date_access', '>=', $request->from)
    ->where('date_access', '<=', $request->to)
    ->selectRaw('DATE(date_access) as date, COUNT(1) as cnt') // created_at here is datetime format, only need the date portion using `DATE` function
    ->orderBy("date")
    ->groupBy("date")
    ->get() // return result set (collection) from query builder
    ->pluck('cnt'); // only need the cnt column

// Sum
$matchSum = $match->sum();

// Convert to array (if really needed)
$match = $match->toArray();
```

Comment: i get an error `Call to a member function sum() on array` because the value ->all() is returning array

Comment: Oh, ok - then you need to wrap them in `collect($arr)` first. I'll edit my answer.